# streaming replication postgresql slave not connecting

Tags: postgresql-9.2, database-replication

I am having trouble setting up streaming replication on postgresql. After searching around the web, I came across this

http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/AANLkTim4jZ4Zu2DAha5=HDA=o4d8ch2Tfv10984AYkyp@mail.gmail.com

The psql command works fine for me (except with master IP run on slave). So it seems like its a recovery.conf issue. Here is my file

```
standby_mode          = 'on'
primary_conninfo      = 'host=<masterIP>'
trigger_file = '/tmp/trigger'
restore_command = 'cp /tmp/archive/%f "%p"'
```

Is there anything wrong with this? I can post the pg_hba.conf & postgresql.conf files if it seems like the problem might be there.

Answer (score 0):

I have done streaming replication and it is working fine.Recovery.conf should contain the IP of master.
The following link:
http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2013/02/16/zero-to-postgresql-streaming-replication-in-10-mins/ helped a lot.